# java local upload and download file

Tags: java

I have a problem that about simple upload and download file. I have a local java program that allow user upload file. eg. a file call abc.txt in desktop upload to the java workspace location, ./upload. However, I use:

```
boolean success = srcFile.renameTo(new File(dir, srcFile.getName()));
```

dir is the destination, the file will cut in the desktop and paste in the ./upload. But I want to copy and paste. Then, the path that store the file will store in the database. how to solve.

Also, after upload, is it possible download the file based on the path that store in the Database ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want preserve the old file then you must not use `renameTo`.

You have to create new file. To do that you can use [copyFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

For example:

```
File srcFile = new File("source.doc");
File destFile = new File(dir, srcFile.getName());
FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, destFile);
```

> Also, after upload, is it possible download the file based on the path
>   that store in the Database ?

Yes it is. If you can use the direct access to the file path always using the `copyFile` function you can copy locally the file using the path on db.